# inserting a row on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to figure out why my code is not working. I have a table with a text field, 2 checkboxes and an add button in a row. I have 4 rows on load, I have a hyperlink when clicked should add a new row at the end of the table. My code is adding the row alternatively starting from the first row. My last row is 4 which I am cloning. The sequence I am getting when click on the link
1,4,2,4,3,4,4,4

I don't understand where I am making a mistake, I have been banging my head for this for last 4-5 hours

```
<table id="setting">
<tr><td><input name="name_1" type="text" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="button" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="name_2" type="text" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="button" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="name_3" type="text" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="button" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="name_4" type="text" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /> </td>
<td><input type="button" /></td></tr>
</table>

$('#add').on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     $clone = $('#settings tbody tr').filter(":last").clone(true).insertAfter('#settings tbody tr').filter(":last").val('');
```

I tried this code below from one of the questions in stackoverflow. This one didn't work for me, i don't know why

```
$('#settings tbody tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#settings tbody>tr:last');
$('#settings tbody tr:last').val('');
```

Comment: Sorry if this this a stupid question, but what is "<portlet:namespace />"?

Comment: `<portlet:namespace />` what is the output?

Comment: I have removed <portlet:namespace /> to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See you don't have `tbody` in the markup there but you are using in the jQuery:

```
<table id="setting">
   //<-----------------------missing tbody here
  <tr>
     <td><input name="name_1" type="text" /></td>
     .................

$('#<portlet:namespace />settings tbody tr:last')
      //--------------------------^^^^^------------its not there
```

Instead you can try this one:

```
$('#<portlet:namespace />settings tr:last')
```

---

### Update:

```
 $('#settings tbody tr')
 //---------^-----------------this makes the mess
```

wrong id selected use `setting` instead `settings`:

```
 $('#setting tr:last-child').clone().insertAfter('#setting tr:last');
```

#### [CHECKOUT THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GwTtD/1/)

### Another update:

```
 $('#add').click(function (e) {
      var $cln = $('#setting tr:last-child').clone();
      $cln.find(':text').attr('id', 'textbox' + $('#setting tr:last-child').index()).val('');
      $cln.find(':checkbox').each(function (i, v) {
          $(this).attr('id', 'check' + $('#setting tr:last-child').index() + i).prop('checked', false);
      });
      $cln.find(':button').attr('id', 'btn' + $('#setting tr:last-child').index());
      $cln.insertAfter('#setting tr:last');
      console.log($cln.find(':text').attr('id') + '<===>' + $cln.find(':checkbox:eq(0)').attr('id') + '<===>' + $cln.find(':checkbox:eq(1)').attr('id'));
 });
```

Comment: it would output a unique id for that jsp which can be accessed from any jsp page. I tried `$('#<portlet:namespace />settings tr:last')` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: It works good, I need to clear the data in the whole row, if the checkboxes are checked they should be clear and also the input text fields

Comment: Also how to add id for textbox, checkboxes and also button

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#setting tr:last-child').insertAfter('<tr><td><input type="button" /></td></tr>');
```

or

```
$('#setting tr:last-child').after('<tr><td><input type="button" /></td></tr>');
```

.after() Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Check this fiddle out : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BectZ/3/) and [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BectZ/4/)

```
$('#add').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#setting tr:last-child').after('<tr><td><input name="name_4" type="text" /></td>td><input type="checkbox" /> </td><td><input type="checkbox" /> </td><td><input type="button" /></td></tr>');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Your code is adding only button in the next row, button is not in a new row. Textbox, 2 checkboxes and button constitute a row

Comment: I just made an example which works, not you can use the code which  it works to add the code you want.

Comment: now it is complete, will update the jsfiddle when i get to a computer.check add click code.